# Javascript + jquery issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a bunch of "tasks" from a database and formatting this way with .each function.

```
$.getJSON('tarefas.php?acao=2', function(data) {
   $.each(data,function(){
      $('.task-item').parents('ul').prepend('
         <li class="task-item nova">
            <div class="status"></div>
            <li id="'+(this).id+'">
               <span class="id">ID: </span>
               <span class="id" id="id_tarefa">'+(this).id+'</span>
               <div class="task-comment">
                  <span class="helper-subtle">14/06/2011 14:32</span> database data
                  <div class="ico-delete"></div>
               </div>
         </li>'
      });
   });
```

And now I need to send this data to a php file and add more one log line when the bt-salvar is pressed.

```
<div class="task-log">
   <span class="helper-subtle">14/06/2011 14:32</span> database data
   <div class="ico-delete"></div>
</div>
```

I am using this code:

```
$('.bt-salvar').click(function() {$.ajax({type: 'POST',
   url: 'tarefas.php?acao=3',
   data: {'dados':'{"tarefa":"'+$('#id_tarefa').text()+'"}'},
   success: function(){
      $('#'+$('#id_tarefa').text()).prepend('
         <div class="task-comment">
            <span class="helper-subtle">data</span>
            '+$('textarea').val()+
            '<div class="ico-delete"></div>
         </div>'
      );
    });
});
```

When I pressed the `bt-salvar` this line is added but just in 1 task. I should the problem is in way that I am referencing the id `($('#'+$('#data-group').text()))`.

I need to get the exact current task and put the log line just on this task. I don´t know how can I reference the current tasks that was generated by the first`.getJSON` part of the page.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as “too localized” — please see the description of the “close reason” for an explanation, then post a new question which might be more generally useful.

Answer (score 0):

You have a `<span class="id" id="id_tarefa">...</span>` but it is being generated with $.each() so presumably you have several of them - identifiers must be unique.

Comment: Thank you very much ! You already helped me to understand the problem ! Thanks ! So, how can I create in Javascript a unique identifier for each task ?

Comment: Where is .bt-salvar located in the DOM?  Are there multiple buttons like that?